# Nothing Happens When UITableView is Clicked (trying to send data between views)

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

So I have a two page app. The purpose of the app being the user can store expenses. They log a `name` and `amount` (attributes) and this data is stored in `Expenses` (entity). I have figured out how to create core data values, delete and retrieve. I am now working on updating. This will work by the user tapping on a table in the first view (`ExpensesViewController`) where the expenses are stored and this takes them to the 2nd view (`EditExpensesViewController`) where they can update the value back into core data. I am stuck on this 'data transfer' between the views.

I am using the storyboard and connected the first view to the second via 'show' set the segue identifier as 'editExpense'. However nothing happens when the table row is tapped. Any idea why it's not working and what I may have missed out? [See here for GIF](https://media.giphy.com/media/7JI6JuqxzN0uZtm44t/giphy.gif)

[image: Picture of the segue]

[image: Outlet connections]

**ExpensesViewController**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ExpensesViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var totalLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var expenses_array = [Expenses]()
    var send_array = [Expenses]()

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        retrieveExpenses()
    }

    func retrieveExpenses(){
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Expenses> = Expenses.fetchRequest()
        do {
            let expenses = try PersistenceService.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            self.expenses_array = expenses
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        } catch  {
            print(error.localizedDescription )
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "editExpense") {
            let secondViewController = segue.destination as! EditExpensesViewController
            secondViewController.send_array = send_array
        }
    }


}

extension ExpensesViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return expenses_array.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = expenses_array[indexPath.row].name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = expenses_array[indexPath.row].amount
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == .delete) {

            let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Expenses> = Expenses.fetchRequest()
            do {
                let result = try PersistenceService.context.fetch(fetchRequest)

                // Delete from Core Data and remove from the arrays then save
                if result.contains(expenses_array[indexPath.row]){
                    PersistenceService.context.delete(expenses_array[indexPath.row])
                    expenses_array = expenses_array.filter { $0 != expenses_array[indexPath.row] }
                    PersistenceService.saveContext()
                    self.getTotalExpenses()
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }

            } catch  {
                print(error.localizedDescription )
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        send_array = [self.expenses_array[indexPath.row]]
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "editExpense", sender: self)
    }

}
```

**EditExpensesViewController**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class EditExpensesViewController: UIViewController {

    var send_array = [Expenses]() // Defined from the previous view controller

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(send_array)

    }
}
```

Comment: If you could add a picture indicating the name of your segue, please, in addition to showing us where the segue connects the ViewControllers.

Comment: put a breakpoin in your `prepare` and check if the condition is true or not

Comment: Yea, but that doesn't show US, as helpers, that your segue is the name you actually say it is, nor does it show us the view controllers that you say are connected. For us to diagnose your problem, we need to see all working pieces related to your issue.

Comment: @impression7vx added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all conform to tableView delegates and dataSource in your viewDidLoad() :

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

Delete segue from stroyboard and we will present the controller in code using :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "editExpense") {
        let secondViewController = segue.destination as! EditExpensesViewController
        secondViewController.send_array = send_array
        // "someIdentifier" is the identifier of secondController in storyboard
         storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someIdentifier")
        present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Be aware to put storyboard identifier for second controller in storyboard using attribute inspector

Comment: @Nouman change your controller extension to this : extension ExpensesViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate

Comment: @Nouman right click on your tableView on storyboard and close tableview delegate and datasource refrence

Comment: @Nouman the last crash was because you have two refrences to tableview one from viewDidLoad and second from storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your first view controller is the UITableViewDataSource only.  That is not enough. It needs to be the UITableViewDelegate too. `didSelectRowAt` Is a delegate method, not a data source method, and will not be called unless this view controller is the table views delegate and is explicitly declared as conforming to UITableViewDelegate.